# microsoft excel driver connection string

Tags: sql, windows, odbc

I have 2 queries :

1) How to add relative path to connection string. For example I want to specify %appdata% folder in odbc connection string.If I give absolute path it works fine as shown below but as per my requirement I want to choose current env config

```
Driver={Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)};dbq=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\myfolder
```

I have tested below method but didn't work for me

```
Driver={Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)};dbq=Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)\myfolder

Driver={Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)};dbq=Environment.GetEnvironmentVaiable("APPDATA")\myfolder
```

2nd question is that can we put web link to dbq in connection strings

```
Driver={Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)};dbq=https://myweburl/data.xls
```

Thanks